# Power dissipation across resistors in series

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

Suppose we have a simple circuit with an input voltage source $V$ and two resistors.

Now if we want to find the power dissipated by each resistor using the formula $V^2/R$, should the voltage be the input voltage or the voltage across that specific resistor.

I have this question because, in a series connection, voltage across different components is different.

Comment: Adding a simple procedure to go with RedGrittyBrick's answer:  First, find the total resistance.  That's easy, just add 'em up.  Then find the current.  That's easy too:  Ohm's Law.  Now calculate the power dissipated in each resistor as $I^2R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **should the voltage be the input voltage or the voltage across that specific resistor**

The latter.

generally when you want to know something about a particular component, you work with the conditions applying at the boundary of that specific component.

I have a desk lamp with a LED. The other end of the lamp plugs into a 240 V AC power outlet. If I want to know the power being dissipated by the LED I need to measure the voltage and current at that LED, not at the wall outlet, not at a power plant that you might consider part of the circuit.

Comment: Why the drive by downvote? This seems a perfectly good answer to me.

Comment: so if there are two resistors R and r, the voltage across say r is Ir where I is V/(R+r) and this value is used in the power formula for the power dissipated by r?

Comment: Yes user34304 that is correct. The same current I flows in each series-connected component.